# Writing Excel file with SuperCsv including font formatting

Tags: supercsv

I use SuperCSV to write Excel files. How can I add font formatting to some of the cells - strikethrough etc.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SuperCSV to write an "Excel" file, you're just writing out a comma delimited file.  If you need to start getting fancy and trying to add fonts, colors and other formatting tools, it may be time to step up from CSV as an output to an actual XLSX / XLSM.  There is a tool out there called Apache POI.  We use that on my team for when we need to have full featured Excel files.  You can find it here: http://poi.apache.org/ Just be forewarned that conversion from SuperCSV to POI is not a fast or easy conversion.